# Can't enable Parse Local Datastore

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, local, datastore

I'm trying enable the Parse Local Datastore. In the Parse Docs, they said to put the code `enableLocalDatastore` **before** `setApplicationId:clientKey:`, but this throws an exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call
>   setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'

Comment: It's not you. It's a universal bug going on right now. Just search SO for other similarly related issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**v1.6.0**

Place the code for enableLocalDatastore after setting applicationId and clientKey. It looks like it was simply a mistake in their documentation.

**v1.6.1+**

Place the code for enableLocalDatastore before setting applicationId and clientKey.

Comment: I've tried do this and i got others errors. But i discovered that the other errors was because when you enable Local Datastore you can't use the Cache Policy's methods. So, Local Datastore and Cache Policy won't work together. Thanks Jordan.

Comment: No it is not. if you put it _after_ `setApplicationId`; it throws an error says we should put it _before_ it.

Comment: The answer has now been updated to reflect the most recent update.

Comment: @JordanJohnson this gives me a warning in 1.6.1 to put it before!

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure you don't have any cachePolicy set in your code.
In my case I had

```
query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache
```

There is not need of a cache now you have your data in a local database.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error.

I commented this line" // query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheElseNetwork" and it works.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)
if(objects?.count == 0){
   //query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheElseNetwork
    }
    query.orderByAscending(Column Name")
    return query
}
```