# Cannot Enable Parse Local Datastore in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, local-database

I'm having the same issue as described here: [Can't enable Parse Local Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464690/cant-enable-parse-local-datastore)

However, I do not understand what he is talking about when he talks about Cache Policy.

Can someone please help me fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: if you'r having some trouble, uploade somecode where the error is, if it's allergy allready when the apps opens paste the error here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have the line that goes somewhat

```
query.cachepolicy = something something
```

if you do delete it

also in app delegate put the "enable localstore" AFTER Parse.clientkey....

Comment: Should cachepolicy be in my app delegate?

Comment: It doesn't look like I have it.

Comment: good then you don't have that error he has, the one your posted link til